# Spivak's Calculus: Understanding proof of alternative form of l'Hôpital's Rule

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, proof-explanation

The following problem is from chapter 11, "Significance of the Derivative", of Spivak's Calculus.

> 55. There is another form of l'Hôpital's Rule which requires more than
>     algebraic manipulations: If $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) =
>     > \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \infty$, and $\lim\limits_{x \to
>     > \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=l$, then $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}
>     > \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=l$. Prove this as follows.
>
> (a) For every $\epsilon>0$ there is a number $a$ such that
>
> $$\left | \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} -l \right | < \epsilon, \text{ for }
>  x>a$$
>
> Apply the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem to $f$ and $g$ on $[a,x]$ to show
> that
>
> $$\left | \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}-l \right | < \epsilon, \text{
>  for } x>a$$
>
> (Why can we assume $g(x)-g(a) \neq 0$?
> (b) Now write
> $$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}\cdot \frac{f(x)}{f(x)-f(a)}\cdot \frac{g(x)-g(a)}{g(x)}$$
> (why can we assume that $f(x)-f(a) \neq 0$ for large $x$?) and conclude that
> $$\left | \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-l \right | < 2\epsilon \text{ for sufficiently large } x$$

**My question is about the proof of part (b).**

Here is a proof of $(a)$

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=l$ means that

$$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists a>0\ \forall x, x\geq a \implies \left | \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}-l \right | < \epsilon\tag{1}$$

Therefore $f$ and $g$ are differentiable on $[a, +\infty)$ and $g'(x) \neq 0$ on $[a,+\infty)$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $a>0$ satisfying $(1)$.

Let $x \in (a, +\infty)$.

Apply the Mean Value Theorem to $g$ on $[a,x]$.

$$\exists c, c \in (a,x) \land \frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-b}=g'(c)$$

Assume $g(x)-g(a)=0$. Then $g'(c)=0$. $\bot$.

Therefore, $g(x) - g(a) \neq 0$.

Now apply the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem to $f$ and $g$ on $[a,x]$.

$$\exists \alpha_x, \alpha_x \in (a,x) \land [f(x)-f(a)]g'(\alpha_x)=[g(x)-g(a)]f'(\alpha_x)$$
$$\implies \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}=\frac{f'(\alpha_x)}{g'(\alpha_x)}$$

But from $(1)$ we know that

$$l-\epsilon<\frac{f'(\alpha_x)}{g'(\alpha_x)}<l+\epsilon$$

Hence,

$$l-\epsilon<\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}=\frac{f'(\alpha_x)}{g'(\alpha_x)}<l+\epsilon$$

$$\left | \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)} - l \right |<\epsilon$$

And this is true for any $x>a$.

**Here is a proof shown in the solution manual for part (b):**

We have

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}\cdot \frac{f(x)}{f(x)-f(a)}\cdot \frac{g(x)-g(a)}{g(x)}$$

where $f(x)-f(a) \neq 0$, $g(x) \neq 0$ for large enough $x$, since $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} g(x)=\infty$. These limits also imply that

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{f(x)-f(a)}=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{g(x)-g(a)}{g(x)}=1$$

It follows that $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ can be made as close to $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}$ as desired by choosing $x$ large enough.

Together with part $(a)$, this shows that

$$\left | \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-l \right | < 2\epsilon \text{ for sufficiently large } x\tag{2}$$

**Questions**

How do we prove that

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{f(x)-f(a)}=1$$

How do we actually obtain $(2)$ from part $(a)$?

Intuitively, $\frac{f(x)}{f(x)-f(a)}$ and $\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{g(x)}$ are both approaching $1$, and so $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is approaching whatever $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}$ is approaching, which is $l$.

In fact $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}\cdot \frac{f(x)}{f(x)-f(a)}\cdot \frac{g(x)-g(a)}{g(x)}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}\cdot \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{f(x)-f(a)}\cdot \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{g(x)}$$
$$=l\cdot 1 \cdot 1$$
$$=l$$

But how exactly do we obtain $2\epsilon$?

Comment: $f(x)-f(a)$ tends to $\infty$ , so $f(x)-f(a)\ge 1$ for large $x.$ Next $${f(x)\over f(x)-f(a)}=1 +{f(a)\over f(x)-f(a)}$$ tends to $1.$